# Downloading a file by using a service

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, download

To download some files on lots of activities, I thought it will be much better to integrate all the same codes into one activity like (DownloadFiles.class), but here is the problem. I have to get a progress value into my main activity (SetupActivity.class), it is impossible to do that using AsyncTask. The original code was:

```
private class DownloadFiles extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private Context context;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    public DownloadFiles(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... input_value) {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(input_value[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream(new File(input_value[1]));
            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                    return null;
                }
                total += count;
                if (fileLength > 0)
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null) output.close();
                if (input != null) input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored){
                ignored.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "Download Complete.";
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                getClass().getName());
        mWakeLock.acquire();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mWakeLock.release();
        if (!result.equals("Download Complete.")) {

        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

It was unable to use onProgressUpdate to handle other activities' progressbar. The reason why I am not using **ProgressDialog** is since it is deprecated, it is much better to use the Progressbar which doesn't prevent user from interacting with user interfaces.

I heard that using services is one of the answers, but there are no ways to update progressbar with my knowledge.

Comment: use broadcast receiver, send broadcast on progress update and receive it in activity and update your progressbar there.

Comment: Do you mean using an asynctask but adding a broadcastreceiver?

Comment: yeap.. exactly what i meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also pass a callback value to the AsyncTask like this:

```
private class DownloadFiles extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
private Context context;
private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
private ProgressCallback mProgressCallback

public DownloadFiles(Context context, ProgressCallback callback) {
    this.context = context;
    mProgressCallback = callback
}
```

Then you create an interface like this:

```
public interface ProgressCallback{ 

   void onProgressUpdate(int percentComplete);
```

Have every activity or fragment which needs to show the progress implement this interface and then you can call from onProgressupdate in the asyncTask:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        mProgressCallback.onProgressUpdate(progress[0])
    }
```

You can tweak the interface and method whichever way you like.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This might be the key for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

See, as you might know, services runs on the background thread hence there is no chance for you to update the progressbar.

But, as an alternative you can use the progressbar on the Notification section, like how youtube does when reviewing offline videos or downloading any videos.

On the other hand, your idea of using one DownloadFiles.class is excellent. So, why not call when the activities open and show progress bar, update views etc etc.

There will be no need of service too.

Comment: Since it is a fullscreen application which means users have to open the notification bar in order to check the progress of file downloading process, I think it is not a good option to use Notification.

Comment: Oh Okay then you can try the other method mentioned below the Notification thingy.

Comment: `which means users have to open the notification bar ` No. You can do that for them programmatically.

Comment: @greenapps could you be more specific?